# android Async Task for proper usage of ui thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below is my prepared code which listens for location updates and once the location is within a designated area, it will connect to a server and will start sending it's locations and time stamps until it exit the area.

I was advised that the different methods may stress out the ui thread and that i need to have the network connection to run in the background or on a separate thread to prevent slow down in the application.

I was reading about [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the android documentation.

Here are my questions:

1. I guess i need to put in a separate thread the part after the app determines that it is inside the designated area (rectangle) and the moment that it is trying to connect and send to the server?
2. How will i do that ?

   ```
   public class GpsActivity extends Activity {

   private LocationManager lm;
   private LocationListener locationListener;
   public static TelephonyManager tm;
   public static TextView tv;
   public static Socket s;
   public static PrintWriter out;


   /**
    * Called when the activity is first created.
    */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   /**
    * retrieve a reference to provide access to information about the telephony services on the device     
    */
   tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   /**
   * retrieve a reference to provide access to the system location services    
   */              
   lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    


    /**
     * explicitly select the provider, create a set of Criteria and let android choose the best provider available
     */

     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
     criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
     criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
     criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
     criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
     String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
     /**
      * This method takes in four parameters:
      provider: The name of the provider with which you register
      minTime: The minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds.
      minDistance: The minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters.
      listener: An object whose onLocationChanged() method will be called for each location update.
      */
      locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
      lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      tv.setText("I currently have no Location Data.");

      }

       /**
        * Connects the Android Client to a given server
        * 
        * @param name
        *            The name of the remote server
        * @param port
        *            Port number to connect to at the remote server.
        * @throws IOException
        * @throws UnknownHostException
        */
       public static void connect(String name, int port)
       throws UnknownHostException, IOException
   {

   s = new Socket(name, port);
   out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
   }

   /**
    * Sends a string message to the server.
    * 
    * @param msg
    *            The message to be sent.
    * @throws IOException
    */
    public static void send(String msg) throws IOException
    {
    if (!s.isClosed() && msg != null)
    {
       out.println(msg);
       if (msg.contains("CMD_QUIT"))
       {
           out.close();
           s.close();
           Log.i("ServerConnection", "Client Disconnected.");
       }
   }
   }

    //Used for receiving notifications from the LocationManager when the location has changed

   private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
       String txt = "Latitude:" + loc.getLatitude() + "/nLongitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
       Log.i("GeoLocation", "My current location is:\n " + txt);
       tv.setText("My current location is:\n" + txt);
       final String msg = loc.getLongitude() + "\n" + loc.getLatitude() + "\n"
          + loc.getTime();


       //determines if the location is within a designated area (rectangle)
       double lat0 = 14.618572;
       double long0 = 120.993816;
       double lat1 = 14.619652;
       double long1 = 120.992770;
       double lat2 = 14.620285;
       double long2 = 120.993451;
       double lat3 = 14.619242;
       double long3 = 120.994497;
       double rel1 = (loc.getLongitude()- long0)*(lat1 - lat0)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat0)*(long1-long0));
       double rel2 = (loc.getLongitude()- long1)*(lat2 - lat1)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat1)*(long2-long1));
       double rel3 = (loc.getLongitude()- long2)*(lat3 - lat2)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat2)*(long3-long2));
       double rel4 = (loc.getLongitude()- long3)*(lat0 - lat3)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat3)*(long0-long3));

       // if yes, it will connect to server and send the location and timestamp


       if (rel1 >= 0 && rel2 >= 0 && rel3 >= 0 && rel4 >= 0 )
       {

           try
           {
           connect("IP address", 27960);
           send("CMD_HELLO");
           send(msg);
           tv.setText("Location is inside the road network...sending coordinates to server");
           send("CMD_QUIT");
           } catch (UnknownHostException e)
           {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e)
           {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           }


       else
       {
           tv.setText("Current location is outside the road network");

       }
       }





   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

           }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it and it worked by following the [tutorial](http://mrkn.co/s/video_tutorial_android_application_development_asynctask_preferences_and_options_menu,257/index.html).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 /**
  * retrieve a reference to provide access to information about the telephony services on the device     
  */
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 /**
  * retrieve a reference to provide access to the system location services    
  */              
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    


/**
explicitly select the GPS provider, create a set of Criteria and let android choose 
the best provider available
 */

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
/**
 * This method takes in four parameters:
provider: The name of the provider with which you register
minTime: The minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds.
minDistance: The minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters.
listener: An object whose onLocationChanged() method will be called for each location update.
 */
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("I currently have no Location Data.");

}

/**
 * Connects the Android Client to a given server
 * 
 * @param name
 *            The name of the remote server
 * @param port
 *            Port number to connect to at the remote server.
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 */
 public static void connect(String name, int port)
        throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{

    s = new Socket(name, port);
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
}

/**
 * Sends a string message to the server.
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            The message to be sent.
 * @throws IOException
 */
 public static void send(String outmsg) throws IOException
{
    if (!s.isClosed() && outmsg != null)
    {
        out.println(outmsg);
        out.close();
        s.close();
        }}



  //Used for receiving notifications from the LocationManager when the location has changed

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String txt = "Latitude:" + loc.getLatitude() + "/nLongitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.i("GeoLocation", "My current location is:\n " + txt);
        tv.setText("My current location is:\n" + txt);
        String msg=loc.getLongitude() + "\n" + loc.getLatitude() + "\n"
        + loc.getTime();
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);  
        //determines if the location is within a designated area (rectangle)
        double lat0 = 14.609794;
        double long0 = 120.986018;
        double lat1 = 14.608966;
        double long1 = 120.986037;
        double lat2 = 14.609031;
        double long2 = 120.984991;
        double lat3 = 14.609877;
        double long3 = 120.985069;
        double rel1 = (loc.getLongitude()- long0)*(lat1 - lat0)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat0)*(long1-long0));
        double rel2 = (loc.getLongitude()- long1)*(lat2 - lat1)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat1)*(long2-long1));
        double rel3 = (loc.getLongitude()- long2)*(lat3 - lat2)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat2)*(long3-long2));
        double rel4 = (loc.getLongitude()- long3)*(lat0 - lat3)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat3)*(long0-long3));

        // if yes, it will connect to server and send the location and timestamp

       if (rel1 >= 0 && rel2 >= 0 && rel3 >= 0 && rel4 >= 0 )
        {
           tv1.setText("Location is inside the road network...");
           **new connectSend().execute(msg);**  
           }


        else
        {
            tv1.setText("Current location is outside the road network");

        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    **public class connectSend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result;

            try
            {
            connect("ip address", port);

            send(msg[0]);

            result = "SUCCESSFUL coordinates sent to server";

            } catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = "NOT SUCCESSFUL ";
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = "NOT SUCCESSFUL ";
            }
            return result;}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv2.setText("result");

            }**


}


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi you could use runnOnUIThread(Runnable R) to change the Text.

Anyway with AsyncTask is better because you don't freeze the UI while connecting.